# Python - Change object shape?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Currently I have an element X that has the shape (33,). I'd like to change this to (33, 501), since I know each row does have 501 elements. Fe. `X[0] = [0, 1, 0, 0, .. 0, 1]`
I've tried

```
np.reshape(X, (33,501))
```

But it errors with `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`. Even though each row is 501 long.

Comment: `X` doesn't have any "rows", it's shape is `(33,)`... Clearly you are mistaken.

Comment: what types are `X` and `X[0]`? what is likely to work is `X = np.array(X)`

Comment: `X.dtype` returns `dtype('O')`,` X[0]` is a list.

Comment: Right. You need to understand what a `numpy` array is, and why you would never want an array of lists. It makes no sense, it is essentially now a less useful list of lists. In any event, try working with `arr = np.array(X.tolist())`

Comment: @PaulPanzer `X = np.array(X)`'s shape is still (33,).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well originally it's a column of a pandas dataframe, and I'm trying to somehow convert it to the desired shape of (33, 501), but have no idea how.

Comment: in that case `np.array(list(a))`

Comment: @lte__ yeah, a `DataFrame` containing `list`s is only a little bit less silly. Regardless, `arr = np.array(X.tolist()` should work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! What would be much less silly to do? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you are starting from is not a 2-d array but a 1-d array containing lists as its elements. That may look similar, but is actually quite different.

A typical (there are exceptions) m x n array is a linear block of mn elements together with some "metadata" allowing numpy to interpret your indexing (like a[i, j]) in the correct way.

Your array, by contrast, is a 1d block of object references (pointers in c parlance), so this adds another level of indirection if you want to resolve an individual element. First retrieve the list, then its element.

Your array doesn't offer most of the conveniences and speed improvements a proper numpy array does, so it's probably best to convert it.

Normally, the `np.array` factory converts nested sequences of compatible lengths to as deep an array as possible. Your case is the exception because, technically, it is already an array, so `np.array` just shallow-copies it (it copies the list references but not the lists themselves) including shape.

One way of bypassing this is to cast to list before converting:

```
np.array(list(original_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you have got a list with 33 lists that are 501 long within it.

you can convert that to a 2 dimensional array (a matrix) or dataframe, that can be done in several diferent ways; a simple one would be to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])

counter = 0

for array in X:

    df['column_%d' %counter] = array

    counter = counter + 1
```